# Datetime throwing model state is invalid for date posted to Web API (EF Backed)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

This is the error that I am getting for certain submissions that follow a specific "pattern" as per my logging

```
2016-01-21 01:05:01.5879 ERROR Model state is invalid, will throw a bad request. Model state: {
  "tbl_ExternalContacts.Last_Password_Change": {
    "Value": null,
    "Errors": [
      {
        "Exception": null,
        "ErrorMessage": "The value '19/05/2009 15:17:35' is not valid for Last_Password_Change."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm submitting numerous things to my API and it's only occurring when the first value in the date goes over 12. I should point out I'm in the UK, so our date format is dd/mm/YYYY.

How do I tell ASP.NET to validate dates sent in the model in that format as valid so they actually get processed?

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
 public static void Main()
 {
  string[] dateValues = { "30-12-2011", "12-30-2011", 
                          "30-12-11", "12-30-11" };
  string pattern = "MM-dd-yy";
  DateTime parsedDate;

  foreach (var dateValue in dateValues) {
     if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateValue, pattern, null, 
                               DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
        Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1:d}.", 
                          dateValue, parsedDate);
     else
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date and time.", 
                          dateValue);
  }
}
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx